# $\langle T\rangle$, Subring generated by $T$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and  $T\subseteq R$ with $T\not =\emptyset$. Demonstrate that:

$$ \langle T \rangle = \ \cap \{S: \text{S is a subring of R and T} \subseteq S \}$$

is the smallest subring of $R$ to contain $T$.

NOTE : $\langle T\rangle$ is called the subring generated by $T$

**Proof:**

Firstly, $\langle T\rangle$ is an intersection of subrings that contain $T$, then  we can assert $T \subseteq\langle T\rangle$ and also $\langle T\rangle$ is a subring of $R$

To verify $\langle T\rangle$ is the smallest subring of $R$ to contain $T$, I have done the following:

Suppose $K$ is a subring of $R$. If $T \subseteq K$. Is it true that $\langle T\rangle\subseteq K$?

$x \in \langle T\rangle\Longrightarrow x \in\cap \{S: S\text{ is a subring of }R\text{ and }T \subseteq S \}\Longrightarrow x \in S$, for all $S$ subrings of $R$ verifying $T \subseteq S$.

In particular, we know $K$ is a subring of $R$ that satisfies $T \subseteq K$. Then, $x \in K$

Is this final part sufficient to prove $\langle T\rangle$ is the smallest subring of $R$ to contain $T$?

Comment: Good work.  The only minor thing is to make sure that $\langle T \rangle$ is not empty.  In other words, at least one subring must contain $T$.

Comment: We could take the proper subring R, because we know contains T. Thanks for your apportation!